# How to send JSON data via checkbox value?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json, forms, checkbox

I am having hard time sending some JSON data as a checkbox value. When I tried to send the JSON value, I receive only the first word as a value i.e '"{", but I need the whole chunk value. What may be the possible solutions ?

value to be send as checkbox value:

```
{
"audio_uri"=>
 "http://testing.s3.amazonaws.com/N7jcpdkaVH-part_137768534157151.mp3",
 "audio_begin_time"=>"80",
 "audio_length"=>"9540",
 "video_title"=>"apple_boy_cat",
 "text"=>"heoolo \r\n\r\n\r\nI \r\n\r\nAm \r\n\r\n please help me..."
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone help me resolving this problem.

Comment: Could you post your HTML view code and the Function as well.

Comment: @Pavan The HTML look like this

`<input class="select_gs_data" id="gs_data_" name="gs_data[]" type="checkbox" value="{" audio_uri":"http:="" testing.s3.amazonaws.com="" n7jcpdkavh-split_137768534157151.mp3","audio_begin_time":"80","audio_length":"9540","video_title":"apple=""boy_cat","text":"heoolo="" \r\n\r\n\r\ni="" \r\n\r\nam="" \r\n\r\nchandra"}"="">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try html escaping the json data to be sent.
For rails if your data hash is in `data` variable, you might wanna do `CGI::escape(data.to_json)` for checkbox value and when received in server side, just parse the data.